Issue while perfoming HTTP callout: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error"
I've created a class with a method that performs an HTTP call to an external system. The system received and send data in XML.
When I execute this code to call my web service from an Anonymous Window:
RA_GTSCheckService.performCheck('S119440');

I get this error message:
Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error"

What I've tried:

Add the host in a remote site setting. With or without security enabled, the error appears.
Test the same request in Postman. In postman it works without problems, but from Salesforce the problem appears
I've checked with the team at the web service end, they say they aren't receiving the callout, so that makes me think that the issue is in Salesforce side, which isn't able to send the request.

This is my apex class:
public class RA_GTSCheckService {

/**
* @description D2RCPQ-678. Call the GTS SOAP web service
* to peform the GTS check based on the BPID
* @param newMap The trigger.newMap received from Credit Note Line Trigger
* @return void
*/
public static String performCheck(String bpid) {
    
    // Building the request (test bpid: S119440)
    String requestUrl = <URL Here>;
    
    String requestBody = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
                         '<ns0:IDD0834_SPL_Request_MT xmlns:ns0="urn:rockwellautomation.com:idd0834:SanctionedPartyList">' +
                         '<BPID>' + bpid + '</BPID>' +
                         '</ns0:IDD0834_SPL_Request_MT>';

    // Basic authentication method is equal to the string 
    // 'username:password' encoded in Base64
    String userName = <username-here>;
    String password = <password>;
    String usernamePassword = userName + ':' + password;
    Blob headerValueBlob = Blob.valueOf(usernamePassword);
    String encodedHeader = 'Basic ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValueBlob);
    
    // Sending the request
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint(requestUrl);
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setHeader('Authorization', encodedHeader);
    req.setHeader('Cookie', <cookie value>);
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    req.setHeader('User-Agent', 'PostmanRuntime/7.42.0');
    req.setHeader('Accept', '*/*');
    req.setHeader('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip, deflate, br');
    req.setHeader('Connection', 'keep-alive');
    req.setBody(requestBody);
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpResponse res;
    
    try {
        res = http.send(req);
        
        if (res.getStatusCode() == 200) {
            System.debug('Request successful. Processing response...');
            
            Dom.Document responseDoc = new Dom.Document();
            responseDoc.load(res.getBody());

            // Navigate to the STAT element of the response and retrieve its value
            Dom.XmlNode statNode = responseDoc.getRootElement()
            .getChildElement('T_BPID', null)
            .getChildElement('STAT', null);
            
            // Store the STAT value
            String statValue = statNode.getText();
            System.debug('Extracted STAT value: ' + statValue);
            return statValue;
        } else {
            System.debug('Request failed. Status code: ' + res.getStatusCode());
            System.debug('Response body: ' + res.getBody());
        }
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.debug('Error occurred while performing the check: ' + e.getMessage());
        System.debug('Stacktrace ' + e.getStackTraceString());
    }

    return null;
}

}
I've searched information about this issue but didn't find anything useful. If anyone has an idea about how to fix it, please comment it here.
Thank you!

This is not well-documented, but it looks like you need to set user-agent to SFDC-Callout/[api version], e.g. User-Agent=SFDC-Callout/61.0

@DavidCheng Hi, thank you for you comment. I tried adding that header but obtained the same result. I selected 61.0 as the API version in the console, and also put 61.0 in the header, but nothing. It's a very strange issue

Remove these:  req.setHeader('Cookie', <cookie value>); req.setHeader('Accept', '*/*'); req.setHeader('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip, deflate, br'); req.setHeader('Connection', 'keep-alive'); and try again.

Hi @identigral thanks for the advice. I tried removing those headers and leaving the User-Agent=SFDC-Callout/61.0 but I got the same. It looks like an issue from the web service side and me and my team are investigating to add some certificates into the sandbox, maybe that can help workaround this proxy limitation. Thanks, I'll update this question as soon as I find a solution.
